# How to get a single image to hide website pages during maintenance period

Tags: html, css, overlay, tumblr, foreground

I'm currently trying to get a single image (website under construction) to cover the entire Tumblr website I'm working on, temporarily, without losing any of the underlying HTML and CSS code. Additionally, I'm not sure where to put the image itself (head, body, etc) to get it to cover up the menus and other links that are above the content without changing the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.

**Option 1**

The most efficient way would be to have a new page with just the image and put a temporary redirect on your DNS entry if that is accessible to you. If you do not have access you can add a redirect into the head tag. (If you are looking to eventually have good SEO(Search Engine Optimization) you should be wary how you perform this redirect. Hosting the site before its ready may negatively impact rankings.

**Option 2**

Add the image to a div or the body tag as the background with 100% height and give it a large z-score to raise it above the rest of the content.

Comment: This helped tremendously, thank you! I ended up going with the redirect option, so now I've got it to redirect from my standard blog to a base image website: http://trichat.tumblr.com --> http://trichat.tumblr.com/underconstruction

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you put a `div` in the body, then style it with the following rules:

```
.mask {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Then put the image in this mask `div`. The mask element will fill the page.